# Copying to a USB boot sector on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, usb, boot, bootloader, usb-flash-drive

How to copy a file (boot file) to address zero on a USB flash drive?

I am using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

```
dd if=filename of=/dev/yourusbdrive
```

Note, this will overwrite the partition table of the device!
If that's not what you want, please explain what exactly you want to achieve!

Comment: I want to make dummy OS and load it from usb flash , i have the binary of the bootstrap loader